# Copying large numbers of files

Tags: copy

Trying to backup the contents of a 2 TB external drive to another of equal capacity. Finder copying is extremely slow. Is there a quicker alternative?

Comment: `cp` does it file at a time, writing file system entries etc...  You can clone the drive (copies sectors regardless of what's in them)..  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging

Comment: Have you tried **`cp -b`** ?

Comment: `tar cf - . | pv | (cd /mountpoint; tar xf -)` should be the quickest. BUT your question contains a trap: backups are not about being QUICK. They are about being SECURE. You really should use the answer by Sebastian regardless of speed and time. If it is a USB2 connection a USB3 connection will give you the most speed increase.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using rsync for this:

```
rsync -avP /disk1/ /disk2
```

while `/disk1` and `/disk2` are the mount points of your two disks. The `-a` flag will keep file metadata intact and `-vP` will give you a verbose progress indicator.

Main advantage is that you can stop the process at any time and continue later simply by running the same command again.

Comment: But it will not be quicker ;-)

Comment: But it is more fail safe, which is preferable for backups

Comment: I didn't measure, but I would think it's also quicker than using any GUI tool. But that's just guessing.

Comment: Oh, I agree on all the benefits but it wont be quicker and that's his main concern :D `tar` is going to be the quickest tool (and will also be less secure ;) ) Oh the memories that haunt me after my boss asked me the same question. It took us 8 weeks of testing :-X

Comment: I agree tar is faster. If you get it right and error free the first time.

Comment: why disk1 with slash and disk2 without slash?

Comment: @bagustris this is straight from the "Usage" section of rsync(1): "A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination." If you want symmetry you can add a slash to the destination, it shouldn't make a difference.